# Get byte length of current line in Lua

Tags: neovim, lua

How do I get the length, in bytes, of the current line in Lua?

`vim.api.strlen('foo')` doesn't work

Comment: Lua has unary "sizeof-like" operator `#` This is language core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the vim function `col`:

```
vim.fn.col('$')-1
```